# Subcaption package error in LaTeX

Tags: subcaption

I am new to LaTeX. I tried adding images in parallel. For that I added sub-package I have removed this package. But, I am still getting the following error.

[image]

I am using the 'LaTeX Vorlage für Bachelor-/Master-Ausarbeitungen' template from the following link

https://agrosy.informatik.uni-kl.de/studium/vorlagen

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.